# Grep expression for m3 ha−1

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

I tried to replace **m3 ha−1** into **m<sup>3</sup> ha<sup>−1</sup>** with no success. What is wrong with my expression?

```
(?i)(?<=\<m)3(?= ha\>)-1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The superscript dash is different than the one you use in the Grep:

**m3 ha−1**: has a long dash

**(?i)(?<=\)-1**: has a short dash

Is it not enough this way?

**(?<=ha)-1|(?<=m)3**
[image]